# Socket.IO - Server doesn't send response to client under SSL

Tags: node.js, ssl, https, socket.io, server

I'm comfronted with a big problem with socket.io ans NodeJS.
I try to communicate with the NodeJS server through Socket.IO under HTTPS, but when it's time for the server to send a response to the client, it doesn't do anything.

**I've checked, but it's not a certificate error ! Key and certificate are valid.**

However, without HTTPS, it works perfectly.
Here is my code:

```js
var express = require('express'),
    fs = require('fs');

var config  = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/config.json', 'utf8')),
    options = config.options || {};

var PORT     = options.port,
    SSL_PORT = options.ssl_port;

var app = express(),
    server = require('http').createServer(app);
    io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

server.listen(PORT, function()
{ 
    startServer(io);
});

if (options.ssl_key.length && options.ssl_cert.length)
{
    var sslOpt = {
        key: fs.readFileSync(options.ssl_key, 'utf8'),
        cert: fs.readFileSync(options.ssl_cert, 'utf8')
    };

    var sslServ = require('https').createServer(sslOpt, app),
        ioSsl   = require('socket.io').listen(sslServ);

    sslServ.listen(SSL_PORT, function()
    {
        startServer(ioSsl);
    });
}

function startServer(io)
{
    io.on('connection', function(socket)
    {
        socket.on('msg', function(data)
        {
            io.emit('clientMsg', 'New message !');
        });
    }.bind(this));
}
```

And the client part:

```js
var PORT = 2999,
    secured = false,
    serverName = 'my-website-url',
    completeUrl = 'https://my-website-url.com';

if (completeUrl.substr(0, 5) == 'https')
{
    PORT = 3000;
    secured = true;
}

var socket = io(serverName + ':' + PORT, {
    transports: ['websocket'],
    secure: secured
});

socket.emit('msg', 'I send a msg');
```

I use port 2999 for HTTP and 3000 for HTTPS, when I send a message through the HTTPS server (port 3000), I don't receive the server response, but I receive it on HTTP server (port 2999).

So, under SSL, the server doesn't send a response to clients who are using my HTTPS website.